# Find value of attribute for each product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute

I am trying to find a value of one particular attribute for all products.

[image]

Some products have values for this attribute and I can see it here for example:

[image]

Where should I look for it in the database to find a product with this attribute's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in table called `catalog_product_entity_varchar` by running a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` = 184
```

I hope someone will find this useful.